# Return value from select into Function

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, return, oracle12c

I want to write function which return me value from select:

```
Function Test
IS
   my_select varchar2(200):='select colA from tableA where colB = '||const||'';
BEGIN    
   return my_select;
END;
```

It will return select as string. Should I use "into"?

Or maybe it possible to do something like:

```
..
return 'select colA from tableA where colB = '||const||'';
..
```

Comment: Sounds like maybe you want a ref cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working on `Oracle 12c`, you can utilize the new features such as `RETURN_RESULT` in a `Procedure` and `WITH` clause usage with a `function`. See below:

Using a `Procedure`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Test (p_value in varchar2)
AS
  job_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN
   OPEN job_cursor FOR
   select colA from tableA where colB = p_value;

   DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(job_cursor);
END;
```

Using a Function within `With` clause:

```
WITH
  Function Test (p_value in varchar2) return sys_refcursor
  IS
   ret_cur sys_refcursor;
   BEGIN    
      Open ret_cur for select colA from tableA where colB = p_value;
   return ret_cur;
  END ;
SELECT Test ('ABC') ---passing Input to function
FROM  DUAL;
```

Comment: one more @XING - if the procedure is inside package and "p_value" is declared as global  CONSTANT, how to use it ?

Comment: @4est ..Sorry i couldnot understand what you wanted to do. May be you can post a question with all the things you are trying to do.

Comment: if somewhere in the package body I got like: p_value CONSTANT varchar2(30) := 'city2'....so I don't want to pass the p_value but use my CONSTANT

Comment: @4est So in that case you can put it as `PROCEDURE Test (p_value in varchar2 DEFAULT 'city2'`. You cannot have the same name `p_value` for input. Or you can put it as `PROCEDURE Test (p1_value in varchar2 DEFAULT p_value`

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using a ref cursor, like so:

```
Function Test (p_value in varchar2)
return sys_refcursor
IS
   ret_cur sys_refcursor;
BEGIN    
   Open ret_cur for select colA from tableA where colB = p_value;

   return ret_cur;
END test;
```

Note that there is no need for dynamic sql in your case; you can simply bind the value in.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example below gives you a indcation on how you could to solve it. 
 I more like to make use of cursors and records.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Test (vColB IN TableA.ColB%TYPE)
RETURN TableA.ColA%TYPE
AS
    CURSOR cTableA IS
        SELECT ColA FROM TableA WHERE ColB = vColB;
    rTableA cTableA%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN cTableA;
    FETCH cTableA INTO rTableA;
    CLOSE cTableA;

    RETURN rTableA.ColA;
END;
/
```